# Order of inserts to multiple meteor collections

Tags: meteor, ddp

I am seeing unexpected behavior in a basic meteor application that leads to a design pattern question I'd like to pose for comment.

The meteor app has a server that reads a list of graph nodes and edges from an external source, inserts the nodes to a Nodes collection, inserts the edges to an Edges collection, and then inserts a special document into a third Signal collection.  The client has "added:" observers on all three collections to detect changes.

I expected that all the nodes and links would be seen on the client before the signal command to draw.  Instead I'm seeing about 1/3 of the nodes and edges being added AFTER the signal command on the client.

I would like to avoid drawing the graph until after all the data is there, hence the use of the Signal collection.  Is there a better way to do this in Meteor?  Is there a different design pattern I should be using?  Seems like this should be a common question.

```
// server side inserts
_.each(model.nodes, function(r) {
    Nodes.insert({ name: r.name });
});
_.each(model.edges, function(r) {
    Edges.insert({ source: r.src, target: r.tgt, value: r.value });
});
Signal.remove({});
Signal.insert({command: "draw-graph"});


// client side observer
Template.template_mission_impact.rendered = function () {
    var graph = new myGraph(...);

    Nodes.find().observe({
        added: function (doc) {
            graph.addNode(doc._id, doc.name);
        }
    });
    Edges.find().observe({
        added: function (doc) {
            graph.addEdge(doc._id, doc.source, doc.target, doc.value);
        }
    });
    Signal.find().observe({
        added: function (doc) {
            if (doc.command === "draw-graph") {
                graph.draw();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: The callbacks `Nodes.insert` and `Edges.insert` are run asynchronously. It looks like you want to do the `each` loop for `Nodes.insert`, then the `each` loop for `Edges.insert` and then `Signal.remove()` and lastly `Signal.insert()`. But because you're doing callbacks that have DB operations and these operations are run asynchronously, these commands don't necessarily happen in the order you typed. Figure out a way to determine when ALL Nodes and Edges have been added and then run your `Signal.insert` command, or look into JavaScript Promises.

Comment: I don't think the above comment is correct.  _.each() is synchronous and server side meteor collection .insert() calls without a callback are synchronous.  (reference: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert)

Comment: you're correct, sorry about that. On the server inserts without a callback is indeed run synchronously. The OP is experiencing async-like behavior. My guess is that .observe lags behind the server a bit, which is why he is seeing about 1/3 of the nodes and edges being added AFTER the signal command on the client? That doesn't seem to make total sense though since if there is any queueing of observe callbacks going on I would expect the queue to still be in the order of how things were done (ie. Synchronously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema looks fine, just use template subscriptions and wrap your template in a #subscriptionsReady helper. In doing so, the rendered callback won't run until all the docs are there.

In general, graph networks get really big really fast and after about 10000 docs subscriptions will get noticeably slower. If you're data doesn't need reactivity, eliminating it (publishing a fetch, not observing) can give you a serious speed boost.